# Repeat Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building an Angular directive in my index.html page I have:

```
<div bar-chart collectordata="safe.Nodes"></div>
```

This is pulling in an array of Nodes, which is what I would expect. In my directive template I am repeating the element as with as many Nodes as the API call returns.

The Directive spits out the `{{nodes.Label}}` label correctly for each directive. The `id` for the chart correctly adds the 0 based number to the barchart text.

```
<div class="box quarter" ng-repeat="nodes in collectordata">
    <div class="label">{{nodes.Label}} <span>(<a href="#_">History</a>)</span></div>
    <div class="chart" id="{{'barchart' + $index}}"></div>    
</div>
```

The problem I am having is working with each node array individually within the directive `link:` function.

I have tried:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var test = scope.collectordata[$index];
});
```

Which doesn't return anything. When I just use `scope.collectordata` I get both array values. How can I isolate one of the items in the array to work with within some functions on the directive?  Even something as simple as setting an `alert(n)` function.

Do I need to create a `for` loop inside the `link` to access the values?

***This is working, but not sure if it is best practice***

```
var items = scope.collectordata;

d3Service.d3().then(function (d3) {
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var bar = d3.select("#barchart" + i)
        .select("div")
        .style('width', function () {
            return 100 * (items[i].Value / items[i].Max) + "%";
        })
        .text(items[i].Value);
    };              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$index is not available to your directive code. It is defined in an inner scope only.

I think you should create a child directive and pass required data to it, like $index.

```
<div class="box quarter" ng-repeat="nodes in collectordata">
    <div collectordata-child="{{$index}}" class="label">{{nodes.Label}} <span>(<a href="#_">History</a>)</span></div>
    <div class="chart" id="{{'barchart' + $index}}"></div>    
</div>
```

`collectordata-child.link` could then access repeat index.

**UPDATE**

```
.directive('myPane', function() {
  return {
    require: '^collectordata',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      index: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, collectordataCtrl) {
      collectordataCtrl...;
    }
  };
```

Comment: would i need to list it in the scope element in the directive?

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand...list it?

Comment: add it here `scope: { collectordata: '=', }`

Comment: Yes, but it would not be collectordata, but you need access to index. If you need access to collectordata, you could pass collectordata[$index] to the directive, or use `require` on directive definition object.